# XMPP Framework in IOS

Tags: ios, iphone

I am creating an application for IOS which is based on business chat application which is used to chat and also send attachments also can some one help me what are the methods i have to use

Comment: please read documentation first, https://github.com/robbiehanson/XMPPFramework/wiki/GettingStarted_iOS

Answer (score 2):

There is an excellent iOS framework for XMPP [here](https://github.com/robbiehanson/XMPPFramework).
You can find getting started and installation information [here](https://github.com/robbiehanson/XMPPFramework/wiki/GettingStarted_iOS)
There is also a nice tutorial using the above said XMPPFramework [here](http://code.tutsplus.com/series/building-a-jabber-client-for-ios--mobile-22620)

Hope the above links help you.

Answer (score 1):

The most used XMPP iOS framework is [XMPPFramework](https://github.com/robbiehanson/XMPPFramework).
It provides a core implementation of RFC-3920 (the XMPP standard). It comes with multiple [popular extensions](https://github.com/robbiehanson/XMPPFramework/wiki/XEPs) (XEP's). The framework is massively parallel and thread-safe. Performance is good thanks to GCD.

Alternative can be:

- [DCXMPP](https://github.com/daltoniam/DCXMPP) but it hasn't been maintained since 2014.
- [Libstrophe](http://strophe.im/libstrophe/) which is a C library. You can find an iOS version [here](https://github.com/gameclosure/libstrophe-ios). Same it hasn't been maintained since 2013

Answer (score -2):

XMPP is the available best solution for chatting applications in iOS. You can get official documents regarding XMPP extensions [here](http://xmpp.org/xmpp-protocols/xmpp-extensions/).

Answer (score -2):

XMPP Extensions
XMPP is the Extensible Messaging and Presence Protocol, a set of open technologies for instant messaging, presence, multi-party chat, voice and video calls, collaboration, lightweight middleware, content syndication, and generalized routing of XML data.

see more http://xmpp.org/xmpp-protocols/xmpp-extensions/